# Setting up Cucumber with Android

Tags: java, android, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I'm trying to integrate Cucumber into my android project, I'm using [this github project](https://github.com/sebaslogen/CleanGUITestArchitecture) as a guide.

When I run `connectedCheck`, i get this error:


`Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: class name (cucumber/api/java/ko/하지만) does not match path (cucumber/api/java/ko/���������.class)`

I'm using 2.4.0-alpha3 gradle plugin.
These are the dependancies I'm using for cucumber:
info.cukes:cucumber-android:1.2.4
info.cukes:cucumber-picocontainer:1.2.4
info.cukes:cucumber-jvm-deps:1.0.3

I've tried cleaning the project and rebuilding and the same issue happens,
is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Does it launch the tests? or it throws this error even before the tests are run?

Comment: I got it to start launching tests, however each test just throws this error `java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor`

Comment: Can you please paste the entire error logs? There can be two cases.

1. Either your first step is the same for all the tests, and has a wrong code.
2. Or, there can be something wrong with the versions in the set up.

Going by your comment, I guess, the app itself doesn't launch. Please paste the entire logs(atleast few lines before the error text)